# Haskell element of list

Tags: list, haskell

```
elem (1,2,3) [(1,2,3)] -> works (true)

elem (1,2,_) [(1,2,3)] -> doesnt work (want it return true as well)
```

What Im trying to do is if the first two elements of tuple matches one in the list return true.

Comment: i mean how can i make it work.

Comment: I believe the question is: Is there a way to do partial matches on tuples like you would do full matches with the elem function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the prelude function `any` to find out whether at least one element in a list meets a given condition (the condition in this case being "it matches the pattern `(1, 2, _)`").

An example for this case would be:

```
any (\x -> case x of (1,2,_) -> True; _ -> False) [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
```

Or a bit more concisely:

```
or [True | (1,2,x) <- [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]]
```

Comment: can you give an example usage?

Comment: `matchElem (r,s,_) = any (\(a,b,_) -> a == r && b == s)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `elem` if convert the triples to pairs first:

```
elem (1,2) $ map (\(a,b,_) -> (a,b)) [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
```